# C# extract content from HTML document

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7

I was wondering how can I do something similar to Facebook when a link is posted or like shortening link services that can get the title of the page and its content.

Example:

[image: example]

My idea is to get only the plain text from a web page, for example if the url is an article of a newspaper how can I get only the news's text, like showed in the image. For now I have been trying to use the HtmlAgilityPack but I can never get the text clean.

Note this app is for Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track with `HtmlAgilityPack`.

If you want all the text of the website, go for the `innerText` attribute. But I suggest you go with the `meta description` tag (if available).

**EDIT** - Go for the `meta description`. I believe that's what Facebook is doing:

*Facebook link sample*

[image: Facebook link sample]

*Site source*

[image: Site source]

Comment: yes i have tried the innerText but the result is somethind like this: http://pastebin.com/pjdG4NV6 , the result i wanted is between lines 505 and 518.

Comment: In that case, I highly suggest you go with the `meta description` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the example, i think now that i understand how they do it. I now will try to use the description to get the full article text.